# Adding an else statement to page count?

Tags: php, redirect, count

I have a page count to limit the number of times a logged out user can view profiles. If a user is logged out they are redirected to a sign-up page, this is right and should be what's happening but i'm getting the same thing happen when the user is logged in, how can i add an else statement or if statement to say only redirect to sign up page or only limit profile hits if not logged in?

Thanks

```
<?
!session_id() ? session_start() : null;

verify_profile_visit_limit();

function verify_profile_visit_limit(){
    $free_profiles = array(99999,99998,99997,99996,99995,99994,99993);

    if(in_array($_GET["id"], $free_profiles)) return;

    if(! isset($_SESSION["page_access_count"])){
        $_SESSION["page_access_count"] = 1;
    }

    $_SESSION["page_access_count"]++;

    if($_SESSION["page_access_count"] > 5){
        header("Location: limit.php");
        exit();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you got a boolean in the session to say if they are logged in/out?

Comment: Where is your "log the user in" code?

Comment: yes i have got boolean, but i basically need to change the script to say if not logged in do the code if logged in then ignore the code.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `OR` condition so you `return` if the user is logged in:

```
 if(in_array($_GET["id"], $free_profiles) || isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn']) return;
```

With that your function will return before running the limit check. Assuming you store a boolean (`true`/`false`) in `$_SESSION['loggedIn']`.