# run script only when not logged in?

Tags: php, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding an else statement to page count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045922/adding-an-else-statement-to-page-count)

I am using a php page count script. it counts the number of times a non logged in user can access a page before redirecting them to a sign up page.

Basically non logged in users can view other users profiles up to a maximum of 5 times before being redirected to sign up. but this is also happening for logged in users, the page count is counting the number of times and redirecting users who are logged in. i only want the page count to run and redirect if users are not logged in.

Can someone show me what i need to put in the code to make it do this please?
I have tried everything but can't figure it out.

```
<?
!session_id() ? session_start() : null;

verify_profile_visit_limit();

function verify_profile_visit_limit(){
    $free_profiles = array(99999,99998,99997,99996,99995,99994,99993);

    if(in_array($_GET["id"], $free_profiles)) return;

    if(! isset($_SESSION["page_access_count"])){
        $_SESSION["page_access_count"] = 1;
    }

    $_SESSION["page_access_count"]++;

    if($_SESSION["page_access_count"] > 6){
        header("Location: limit.php");
        exit();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `$_GET` here - `/index.php?id=99999`

Comment: You're not storing the login status inside your session?

Comment: @irrelephant I don't see how that's even relephant.

Comment: `!session_id() ? session_start() : null;` Unless I'm mistaken `session_id()` will always return false if called before `session_start()` - so it seems a bit redundant. where did you pick up that line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Right before you call the function `verify_profile_visit_limit()` you should have something like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && empty($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    verify_profile_visit_limit();
}
```

For that to work you would need to set a flag variable such as `$_SESSION['logged_in']` when an user logs in, to check if an user is logged in or not.

So your `verify_profile_visit_limit()` function will only run when users aren't logged in.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for this but it doesn't seem to work, unless i'm writing it wrong? i have this:

Comment: <?
!session_id() ? session_start() : null;

if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && empty($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    verify_profile_visit_limit();
}

function verify_profile_visit_limit(){
    $free_profiles = array(99999,99998,99997,99996,99995,99994,99993);

    if(in_array($_GET["id"], $free_profiles)) return;

    if(! isset($_SESSION["page_access_count"])){
        $_SESSION["page_access_count"] = 1;
    }

    $_SESSION["page_access_count"]++;

    if($_SESSION["page_access_count"] > 6){
        header("Location: limit.php");
        exit();
    }}
?>

Comment: When an user logs in, the program needs to update the session so that the rest of the program knows when an user is logged in or not. So in your login script add this line of code: `$_SESSION[logged_in'] = true;`